# Парсинг всплывающей подсказки на Python

Tags: python, html, парсер, веб-скрейпинг

```
<div class="starsPopover" data-container="#shortPopover" data-content='&lt;table class="GridView"&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td colspan="2"&gt;&lt;b&gt;EMIR&lt;/b&gt; - statistics for 30 days&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;Orders&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;1&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;Refusals&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;0%&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;On time&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;100%&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;Late&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;0%&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt;' data-original-title="" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" id="cphBody_ucSearchPart_repGroups_repSearchAggregate_0_ucSearchPart_Prices_0_repPrices_0_ucSearchPart_PriceItem_0_starsRating_0" style="cursor: pointer; white-space:nowrap;" title="">
```

Нужно вытащить все значения из тега Div с помощью скрейпинга или парсера, далее в тег Div вложенны пять фотографий и после он закрывается. Вся суть вопроса в том как вытащить строки "EMIR, Orders, Refusals, On time, Late, 1, 0%, 100%, 0%" .Заранее благодарю за помощь

Comment: В вашем вопросе нет вопроса

Comment: Попробуйте BeautifulSoup

Comment: Я подключаюсь через Selenium, и потом выгружаю HTML код с помощью BeautifulSoup, но когда обращаюсь к этому диву или к любому элементу в этом диве и вывожу с помощью .text, он выводит пустоту, без [] или None